# How does the pH of fresh glacial meltwater compare to marine seawater?

Tags: ph, geochemistry

How does the pH of fresh glacial meltwater (at the time of melting, so it has not travelled downstream for example) compare to marine seawater? I assume that glacial ice is more neutral since it cannot uptake as much alkalis into its structure. Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the pH of seawater can range from 7.5 to 8.4 depending on where you are in the world, this is due to temperature differences, shipping activity, pollution, and several other factors. Reefs are quite sensitive to pH and are usually found in bodies of water with a pH ranging from 8.0 - 8.4. Glacial water should be *nearly* neutral as most glaciers were formed thousands of years ago when pollution levels were relatively low. It is quite possible that the glacier would actually be *very* slightly acidic due to the carbon dioxide that would have been trapped in the ice when it formed bubbling through the water creating a *very* weak carbonic acid. Scientists actually measure the levels of carbon dioxide in the ice to get an idea of what the Earths atmosphere was like thousands of years ago.

Other users please feel free to correct me if I am incorrect in my answer,  hopefully you can find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Glaciers advance and retreat seasonally. If $\ce{CO2}$ in the cryosphere can correctly reflect its atmospheric concentration of thousands of years ago, than fresh snow must reflect its present atmospheric concentration. See: http://chemistry.elmhurst.edu/vchembook/191acidsnow.html